# Как получить в коде значение, полученное от бота

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть бот на aiogram, который получает от пользователя два значения - инн и банковские реквизиты. Я пытаюсь вытащить их, чтобы дальше использовать в своем коде, но при обращении к UserState получаю <State 'UserState:inn'>, а обрашение к data['inn'] не работает. Как мне можно получить эти значения? Вот код:

```
class UserState(StatesGroup):
inn = State()
number = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def user_register(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите ИНН")
    await UserState.inn.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.inn)
async def get_username(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(inn=message.text)
    await message.answer("Введите реквизиты")
    await UserState.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.number)
async def get_address(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(number=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await message.answer(f"ИНН: {data['inn']}\n"
                         f"Реквизиты: {data['number']}")

    await state.finish()
```

Comment: для таких манипуляций, в случае с большим потоком пользователей - это не сработает. Вам нужна база данных.

Comment: а если поток пользователей совсем небольшой?

Comment: Разницы большой на самом деле нет. Вам нужна бд, или место где вы хотите хранить эти данные. Опять же смотря какую цель вы преследуете.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserState(StatesGroup):
inn = State()
number = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def user_register(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите ИНН")
    await UserState.inn.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.inn)
async def get_username(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['inn'] = message.text
    await message.answer("Введите реквизиты")
    await UserState.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.number)
async def get_address(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        inn = data['inn']
    await message.answer(f"ИНН: {inn}\n"
                         f"Реквизиты: {message.text}")

    await state.finish()
```

Comment: не работает. мне нужно что-то аналогичное тому, как если бы я создавала глобальную переменную inn = 123